# Mysql query to reindex items

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table as follows, it has an ID and item name,order and type.

```
  +--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
  |  ID    |  ITEM          |   ORDER   |  TYPE   |
  +--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
  |  1     |  Banana        |    2      |  Fruit  |
  +--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
  |  2     |  Apple         |    1      |  Fruit  |
  +--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
  |  3     |  Orange        |    4      |  Fruit  |
  +--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
  |  4     |  Lemon         |    3      |  Fruit  |
  +--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
```

If I were to delete say `Lemon` the `ORDER` would be 1,2,4. Is there a method to reindex the remaining items to get the following result?

```
  +--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
  |  ID    |  ITEM          |   ORDER   |  TYPE   |
  +--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
  |  1     |  Banana        |    2      |  Fruit  |
  +--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
  |  2     |  Apple         |    1      |  Fruit  |
  +--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
  |  3     |  Orange        |    3      |  Fruit  |
  +--------+----------------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: is id a unique id? If so, I highly suggest against changing it, especially on all items in your table.

Comment: Id is unique and auto. I only need to reindex ORDER

Comment: alright, I misread it.  Carry on :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right before you delete the `Lemon` row - check what its `ORDER` column value is.

After that perform

```
UPDATE tbl SET `ORDER` = `ORDER` - 1 WHERE `ORDER` > value_lemon_had
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this completely automatically, but it would be fairly simple to do.  Assuming that `ORDER` is not unique it's easier, but if it is you would have to retrieve the `ORDER` of "Lemon" first.  Then, just do:

```
UPDATE Fruit SET ORDER = ORDER - 1 WHERE ORDER > ?
```

Where `?` is Lemon's `ORDER`.

Assuming `ORDER` is not unique, then you could just do this query beforehand, but you would join on `Fruit` selecting Lemon's order to replace `?`.